# Chrome seems to be caching 307 redirects and without the port

Tags: nginx, redirect, browser-cache

I have a website, and, for reasons that don't matter (hard constraint is that another process must listen on 443), I need to host the https version on a nonstandard port (8443 in this case).  I'd like http requests on port 80 to be redirected.  I did some googling on this, and have tried a ton of combinations, before I came up with the following nginx server directives:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 307 https://$host:8443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 8443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:8443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl on;
    error_page  497 https://$server_name:8443$request_uri;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/example.com.key;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

    }
}
```

Now - it sort of works.  `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com:8443`.  But the correct redirect works ***once and only once.*** After the first successful redirect, subsequent requests get rewritten in the browser as `https://example.com` without the port.  I can get the correct behavior again by clearing my browser cache, and can confirm that `curl -Iv http://www.example.com` shows the correct 307 code and port are being provided.